# How to connect telegram bot to local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I want to transfer the bot to my server. I created a local server, but also did not understand how to start it. I created a server on beget, transferred the bot there and don’t understand how to force it to send files through my server. I know about https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api, but I don't understand how to do it.

**file index.js**

```
const { Telegraf, Markup, Input} = require("telegraf")
require("dotenv").config()
const text = require('./const') 

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply(`Hello ${ctx.message.from.first_name ? ctx.message.from.first_name       : 'user'}`))
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply(text.commands))

bot.command('video', async (ctx)=> {

try {
    await ctx.replyWithHTML('<b>Click video</b>', Markup.inlineKeyboard(
        [Markup.button.callback('Video', 'btn_1')]
    ))
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}

})
async function addActionBot(name,path, text) {
bot.action(name, async (ctx) =\> {
try {
if(path !== false) {
await ctx.replyWithVideo(
Input.fromLocalFile("img/2.mp4", '2.mp4')
)
}
await ctx.replyWithVideo(text)
} catch (e) {
console.error(e)
}
})
}
addActionBot('btn_1', 'img/2.mp4', text.text)

bot.launch()

process.once('SIGINT', () => bot.stop('SIGINT'))
process.once('SIGTERM', () => bot.stop('SIGTERM'))
```

**Terminal error**

```
 TelegramError: 413: Request Entity Too Large
at Telegram.callApi (E:\Java\telegrafbot\node_modules\telegraf\lib\core\network\client.js:302:19)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async E:\Java\telegrafbot\index.js:42:17
at async execute (E:\Java\telegrafbot\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:501:17)
at async E:\Java\telegrafbot\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:502:21
at async execute (E:\Java\telegrafbot\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:501:17)
at async E:\Java\telegrafbot\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:502:21
at async execute (E:\Java\telegrafbot\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:501:17)
at async E:\Java\telegrafbot\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:502:21
at async execute (E:\Java\telegrafbot\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:501:17) {

response: {
ok: false,
error_code: 413,
description: 'Request Entity Too Large'
},
on: {
method: 'sendVideo',
payload: {
chat_id: 453138534,
video: \[Object\],
message_thread_id: undefined
}
}
}
```